# How to install the System Monitor plugin for Mate panels?

Tags: mate-desktop, plugin, gnome-system-monitor, mate-panel

I am using MX Linux 21.3 with Mate desktop. I have already installed `mate-system-monitor` (Mate System Monitor 1.24.1). This apparently does not give me the System Monitor plugin that I want for the panels if I choose "Add to Panel". Currently, it is missing from the list:

[image: Current list]

Actually, I do not know whether the plugin should be installed with the Mate System Monitor app itself. I have another Mate desktop using a different Linux distro. Its Mate System Monitor app is also at 1.24.1, and that one has a "System Monitor" in the plugin list for panels, like this (third in the visible part of the list):

[image: Desired plugin list]

Comment: I want this plugin. Not the `multiload-ng` system tray app. That one I am having other issues.